# Display format for repeating value in each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table structure of an organization having 3 columns:

- DEPARTMENT
- SECTION
- SUBSECTION

```
DEPARTMENT  SECTION     SUBSECTION
----------  --------    -----------
A           A1          A101
A           A1          A102
A           A2          A201
A           A2          A202
B           B1          B101
B           B1          B102
B           B2          B201
B           B2          B202
```

And I want to display in a sense that each column, it only display the first appearance of the duplicated value. Expected output as below,

```
DEPARTMENT  SECTION     SUBSECTION
----------  ---------   -----------
A           A1          A101
                        A102
            A2          A201
                        A202
B           B1          B101
                        B102
            B2          B201
                        B202
```

Comment: This should be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: @PM77-1 , that was also my next step if it cannot be done in database layer.

Comment: It can be done with SQL but shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments you should really do this in your application layer; however you can accomplish this with window functions:

```
declare @tmp table (DEPARTMENT varchar(1), SECTION varchar(2),   SUBSECTION varchar(4))
insert into  @tmp values
     ('A', 'A1', 'A101')
    ,('A', 'A1', 'A102')
    ,('A', 'A2', 'A201')
    ,('A', 'A2', 'A202')
    ,('B', 'B1', 'B101')
    ,('B', 'B1', 'B102')
    ,('B', 'B2', 'B201')
    ,('B', 'B2', 'B202')

select
  case when rn_dep = 1 then DEPARTMENT else '' end as DEPARTMENT
, case when rn_sec = 1 then SECTION    else '' end as SECTION
, SUBSECTION
from (
    select 
      DEPARTMENT,SECTION, SUBSECTION
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DEPARTMENT, SECTION, SUBSECTION) as rn_dep
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by DEPARTMENT, SECTION ORDER BY SECTION, SUBSECTION) as rn_sec
    from @tmp
) T
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for this will be more faster, I designed in application layer too.